# How to check github urls

Tags: javascript, regex, handlebars.js

How can I check the a link is a github issue link or github pr link?

Like detect if this link: https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/issues is correct github issue link.

Like detect if this link: https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/pull/1801 is correct github Pull request link.

Found similar question: [Regular expression to match github profile urls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39975639/regular-expression-to-match-github-profile-urls/52053331) :

Regex:  /^(?:http(s)?://)?[\w.-]+(?:.[\w.-]+)+[\w-._~:/?#[]@!$&'()+,;=.]+$/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be specific, you might use jasmine in the url followed by matching either `issues` or `pull/` followed by 1+ digits using an alternation `(?:issues|pull\/\d+)`

*Pattern*

```
https?:\/\/github\.com\/jasmine\/jasmine\/(?:issues|pull\/\d+)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3pCBTi/1)

A more broad match might be repeating 1+ more times matching any char except a `/` or a whitspace `(?:[^\/\s]+\/)+`

*Pattern*

```
https?:\/\/github\.com\/(?:[^\/\s]+\/)+(?:issues|pull\/\d+)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HZRGFa/1)